How do I get my swipe view to delete an item in a collection view located in my flyout?
I'm trying to setup deleting functionality for my term tracking app, but I'm having some issue where when I swipe, the swipe view closes, but no deleting happens. My breakpoint on my DeleteTermAsync method is not even being hit so I'm think there's some issue with the Command="{}" part of the code that is making the DeleteTermAsyncCommand not be hit/found. If anyone knows how I can modify it to make sure it's hit, I'd really appreciate it!
Flyout terms swipe delete
<Shell
    x:Class="TermTracker.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TermTracker"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:TermTracker.View"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:TermTracker.Model"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:TermTracker.ViewModel"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    Title="TermTracker">

    <Shell.FlyoutContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Terms}" ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <SwipeView>
                            <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <SwipeItems>
                                    <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                                               BackgroundColor="Red"
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                               Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:TermViewModel}}, Path=DeleteTermAsyncCommand}" />
                                </SwipeItems>
                            </SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <Grid Padding="10">
                                <VerticalStackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding StartDate, StringFormat='Start: {0:MM/dd/yyyy}'}" FontSize="14"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding EndDate, StringFormat='End: {0:MM/dd/yyyy}'}" FontSize="14"/>
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </SwipeView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.FlyoutContentTemplate>

    <ShellContent Title="Home"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:MainPage}"
                  Route="MainPage"/>
</Shell>


using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using SQLite;
using TermTracker.Model;
using TermTracker.View;
using TermTracker.ViewModel;

namespace TermTracker
{
    public partial class AppShell : Shell
    {
        public AppShell(TermViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = viewModel;
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(AddTermPage), typeof(AddTermPage));
        }
    }
}

using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TermTracker.Model;
using static TermTracker.ViewModel.AddTermPageViewModel;

namespace TermTracker.ViewModel
{
    public partial class TermViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<Term>? terms;

        public TermViewModel()
        {
            LoadTermsAsync();

            // Subscribe to the TermAddedMessage
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<TermAddedMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                LoadTermsAsync();
            });
        }

        async void LoadTermsAsync()
        {
            var termList = await TermRepository.GetTerms();
            Terms = new ObservableCollection<Term>(termList);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        async Task DeleteTermAsync(Term term)
        {
            if (term == null)
                return;

            await TermRepository.DeleteTerm(term);

            // Reload terms
            LoadTermsAsync();  
        }
    }
}

I tried changing the Ancestory type, setting the path to the DeleteTermAsync directly, and adding breakpoints.

Add public to async Task DeleteTermAsync(Term term) and replace Path=DeleteTermAsyncCommand with Path=DeleteTermCommand

@MustafaMutasim My method name was DeleteTermAsync so I though the auto generated code would make my command DeleteTermAsyncCommand but it made it DeleteTermCommand. This worked after fixing someone of my other deletion code. Thank you!

Welcome, Glad it works!

You can refer to the official document about the Asynchronous commands for RelayCommand attribute, and it explains why the async is removed.

My method name was DeleteTermAsync, so I though the auto generated code would make my command DeleteTermAsyncCommand, but it made it DeleteTermCommand. After making that change in my xml, it worked!
